# R converting a vector to a dataframe with one row

Tags: r

I have a vector a<-c(0, 0). I want to convert this to a dataframe and then remove duplicated rows (as part of a loop).

This is my code:

```
a<-c(0, 0)
df<-t(as.data.frame(a))
distinct(df)
```

This isn't working because df isn't a dataframe even though I have converted it to a dataframe in the second step. I'm not sure how to make this work when the dataframe only has one row.

Comment: `t()` converts it to a matrix... Correct syntax is simply `as.data.frame(a)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

swap `t` and `as.data.frame` like this:

```
library(dplyr)
a<-c(0, 0)
df<-as.data.frame(t(a))
distinct(df)
```

Output:

```
  V1 V2
1  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `t` will transform the data.frame back to a matrix. The simplest solution would be to simply change the order of the functions:

```
a <- c(0,0)
df <- as.data.frame(t(a))
distinct(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rbind.data.frame` function as follows:

```
a <- c(0,0)
df = rbind.data.frame(a)
distinct(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` and `matrix`:

```r
library(dplyr)

data.frame(matrix(0, 1, 2)) %>% 
  distinct

#>   X1 X2
#> 1  0  0
```